# Database error while saving the page

Tags: 2011, database

I am facing some database error while saving the page. I am using SDL Tridion 2011 Sp1 version and using Oracle Database 6.1.0.996.

```
Unable to save Page (tcm:202-12456-64).
ORA-01013: user requested that the current operation is interrupted
ORA-06512: at "TCMDBUSER.EDA_ORG_ITEMS", line 4026
ORA-06512: at line 1

Error Code:
0x8004033F (-2147220673)

Call stack:
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32,OracleConnection,IntPtr,OpoSqlValCtx*,Object,String,Boolean)
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32,OracleConnection,String,IntPtr,OpoSqlValCtx*,Object,Boolean)
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean,Boolean,CommandBehavior)
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior)
System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior)
Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.DatabaseUtilities.ExecuteReader(StoredProcedureInvocation,CommandBehavior)
Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Oracle.OracleDatabaseUtilities.ExecuteReader(StoredProcedureInvocation,CommandBehavior)
Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.DatabaseUtilities.ExecuteReader(StoredProcedureInvocation)
Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Oracle.OracleDatabaseUtilities.ExecuteReader(StoredProcedureInvocation)
Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.ContentManagement.OrganizationalItemDataMapper.Tridion.ContentManager.Data.ContentManagement.IOrganizationalItemDataMapper.GetUniquenessConflicts(TcmUri,TcmUri,IDictionary`2)
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.GetConflicts(Dictionary`2)
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.AssertNoUniquenessConflicts(IDictionary`2)
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs)
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs)
Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Page.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs)
Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs)
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.Save(Boolean)
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.Save()
Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.ContentManagement.VersionedItemFacade.UpdateAndCheckIn(UserContext,String,Boolean,Boolean)
XMLState.Save
Page.Save
```

Any ideas on how to solve this error.

Answer (score 3):

That is a timeout error, so you might need to do some database maintenance to improve the performance. For some help in that area, see "[Maintaining an Oracle database](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/idheading-158521840)" on LiveContent (login required). Contact Customer Support if taking those steps doesn't improve the situation.

As a short-term workaround you can try to increase the relevant database timeout values in the SDL Tridion Content Manager configuration. You should focus on solving the performance issue, though, as it will be increasingly frustrating for your users if every action takes forever to complete.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. For time being I would like to increase the time out period values. It would be great if you can show some some steps to do that.

Comment: 1. Open SDL Tridion Content Manager configuration
2. Click Timeout settings in the tree on the left.
3. Change the timeout values on the right.

Comment: 4. restart your server after saving the change

Comment: Better yet, login to the documentation and search for "timeout"...